# Merging objects containing arrays: is it a union?

Tags: javascript, jquery

If I use JQuery's `$.extend` to merge 3 objects, am I supposed to get a union of all object contents?

As an example see my below example; when I merge these objects I am expecting the result:

```
{ hidden: ["foo", "link", "box-shadow"] }
```

But I get:

```
{ hidden: ["link", "box-shadow"] }
```

Is that correct? Any idea if its possible to achieve the result I am expecting/want?

```js
(function() {
  let defaults = { hidden: ["foo"] };
  let options = { hidden: ["link"] };
  let custom = { hidden: ["link", "box-shadow"] };
  let result = {};
  
  $.extend(true, result, defaults, options, custom);
  console.log('result', result);
})()
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Nope, extend doesn't work like this. `let result = { hidden: defaults.hidden.concat(options.hidden, custom.hidden)};`.

Comment: You can use `Object.assign` to merge objects, but it gets a bit trickier if you want a deep copy (also merging child properties). This article explains it nicely: https://medium.com/@tkssharma/objects-in-javascript-object-assign-deep-copy-64106c9aefab

Answer (score 0):

This might be closer to what you need, only using plain Javascript:

```js
(function() {
  let defaults = { hidden: ["foo"] };
  let options = { hidden: ["link"] };
  let custom = { hidden: ["link", "box-shadow"] };
  let result = {
    hidden: [...defaults.hidden, ...options.hidden, ...custom.hidden]
  };
  
  // $.extend(true, result, defaults, options, custom);
  console.log('result', result);
})()
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```